# how the AD user can log in fba site

Tags: authentication, sharepoint-2010, fba

how can FBA site owner who is AD user, can log into FBA site?
do we need to run the User Profile Synchronization Service from central administration ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the web application in the intranet zone and set windows authentication for that particular zone. You can continue to have FBA for the default zone. The portal users will use the default zone whereas you can use the intranet zone to log in using your windows accounts.

Comment: but i am using window authentication  for my default zone and extend(internet zone) uses fba.

Comment: So why can't you login with your windows account in your default zone?

Comment: You can create a FBA user and assign him as the site collection administrator and manage it. But if you are updating content, pages etc. you should be doing it from the intranet zone.